# Directory for Subdomain on Route53

Tags: amazon-ec2, directory, subdomain, amazon-route53, winscp

I've successfully created a subdomain on Route53 that is connected with EC2 Instances. When I access my subdomain *subdomain.domain.com* there appears Amazon Linux AMI Test page.

How to upload my website to *subdomain.domain.com*?
If usually add files to /var/www/html/ on primary domain, what about subdomain?

I also have checked the root server using WinSCP and there is no subdomain directory.

In this case my subdomain is "*blog*".

Hope to get the best answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

`"subdomain.domain.com"` is a logical name (called hostname) for the IP of your EC2 instance. You should not expect any subdomain directory on your EC2 instance. 
It looks like the directory `/var/www/html/` does not have any landing page (`index.html`). Upload your website under the directory `/var/www/html/` such that your `index.html` is placed directly under the directory `/var/www/html/`.